# Can any one give me better solution for merging two sorted arrays into another sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] arrA = {2,3,4};
        int[] arrB = {5,6,7,8};
        mergeArray(arrA,arrB);
    }
    static void mergeArray(int[] arrA,int[] arrB){

        int len = arrA.length+arrB.length;
        int lenA = arrA.length;
        int lenB = arrB.length;
        int a=0,b=0,c=0;
        int temp=0;
        int[] arrC = new int[len];
        for(int i=0; i < lenA; i++){
            arrC[i] = arrA[i];
        }
        for(int j=lenA,k=0; (k < lenB) && (j < len) ; j++,k++){
            arrC[j] = arrB[k];
        }
        for(int n=0; n < len ; n++){
            for(int m=0; m < len; m++ ){
                if(arrC[n] < arrC[m]){
                    temp  = arrC[n];
                    arrC[n] = arrC[m];
                    arrC[m] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int x : arrC){
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

Result: {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

I am trying to put the values into one new array and sorting them again.Can any one give me better solution than this.

Comment: What's wrong with this one?

Comment: I want better solution than this one.@beaker

Comment: Take a look at `System#arrayCopy`

Comment: Is there any solution with out using library methods?? @JonK

Comment: One improvement that should be obvious: Let your mergeArray method actually return the new merged array instead of doing nothing with it so that it will meet the garbage collector soon.

Comment: since the two arrays are already sorted, you can copy the smaller element to the new array, repeat until one input array is exhausted, then copy the rest of the other one.

Comment: There are plenty of solutions for doing it without library methods, but why do you want to avoid them? They're there to be used

Comment: I just need best approach @JonK

Comment: Why are you sorting _after_ copying all the elements? Can't you compare items from `arrA` and `arrB` on the fly and copy the lower one to `arrC`? That way you would have just 1 loop instead of three.

Comment: @user1918566 So you said in the question title. And in the question itself. Your comment doesn't give me any new information as to what is "better" or what you think needs to be improved. If your code is working, this *might* be a better fit for Code Review, but you'd have to check their help center to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recalled old school days! Here is the solution! No libraries, just plain code! Enjoy.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array1 = {5, 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1, 0, 4};
        int [] array2 = {4, 7, 1, 0, 9, 3};

        System.out.println("Array 1");
        print(array1);

        System.out.println("Array 2");
        print(array2);

        Arrays.sort(array1);
        Arrays.sort(array2);

        System.out.println("Sorted array 1");
        print(array1);

        System.out.println("Sorted array 2");
        print(array2);

        int [] mergedAndSortedArray = mergeSorted(array1, array2);

        System.out.println("Sorted merged array");
        print(mergedAndSortedArray);
    }

    private static void print(int [] array) {
        for (int i : array) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    private static int [] mergeSorted(int [] array1, int [] array2) {
        int [] res = new int [array1.length + array2.length];

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        //Do your homework. First loop until you reach end of either array, and then add the rest elements.

        return res;
    }
}
```

This is result

```
Array 1
5 1 4 5 7 8 1 0 4 

Array 2
4 7 1 0 9 3 

Sorted array 1
0 1 1 4 4 5 5 7 8 

Sorted array 2
0 1 3 4 7 9 

Sorted merged array
0 0 1 1 1 3 4 4 4 5 5 7 7 8 9
```

### Update

If you need to merge **N** sorted arrays into a sorted one, you can merge them by pairs recursively (merge first and second arrays, third and fourth, and so on), then again, until you have two arrays, and finally merge them too!

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). **"It's usually better not to provide a complete code sample if you believe it would not help the student, using your best judgment."**

Comment: In addition, "+1" comments are discouraged.

Comment: You created a second answer, rather than editing this one.

Comment: One appropriate answer per user is sufficient.

Comment: @AndyThomas OK, I removed the second answer. I removed the homework solution, just explained in words the idea. Speaking of homework, some other answers are copy-pastable.

Answer (score 2):

Easy. You're concatenating one array after another, then doing a bubble sort. A bubble sort is O(n^2) in the worst case. This means that the time needed to sort may increase with the *square* of the sum of the lengths of the two input arrays.

But you already know that the two arrays are ordered. When writing to the combined array, all you need to look at are the heads of the two input arrays. The next write will be the minimum value of the two. Your merge will be O(n), where n is the sum of the lengths of the two input arrays.

This is one part of a sorting algorithm called [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort). Frequently a merge sort is in-place, in a single array. Yours differs slightly, with the two sorted parts in separate arrays, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java8 Streams:

```
    int[] arrA = {2,3,4};
    int[] arrB = {5,6,7,8};
    int[] mergedArray = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(arrA), Arrays.stream(arrB)).toArray();
```

If the order is important:

```
IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(arrA), Arrays.stream(arrB)).sorted().toArray();
```

In such case you can convert it not only to an array, but to whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Integer[] mergeArray = (Integer[])ArrayUtils.addAll(arrA, arrB);
```

Checkout this:

[public static  T[] addAll(T[] array1, T... array2)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

And then:

```
Arrays.sort(mergeArray, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: I think OP wants an efficient merge sort such that `[1,3,5]` and `[2,4,6]` merge to `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: Why would you convert the integer values to Strings?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for a way to "zip together" two arrays that are already sorted, so that you end up with a sorted array. I think you've realised that concatenating then sorting is inefficient, because it doesn't take advantage of the input arrays being sorted already.

I also assume that this is a homework or study question, so I'm going to describe the solution at a high level.

You need a few variables to track where you are:

- leftIndex (where you are on the left input)
- rightIndex (where you are on the right input)
- destinationIndex (where you are in the destination)

Start with all the indexes at zero. Now we're going to pick an array to work from, and take values from it one by one.

As long as those values are less than the next value from the other input array, we add it to the output. Then we switch over to the other array. We keep switching back and forth until we've reached the end of both inputs.

Pseudocode:

```
while (leftIndex and rightIndex are both within the length of their arrays) {
    while(leftInput[leftIndex] is less than rightInput[rightIndex]) {
         copy leftInput[leftIndex] into destination[destinationIndex]
         increment leftIndex
         increment destinationIndex
    }
    while(rightInput[rightIndex] is less than leftInput[leftIndex]) {
         copy rightInput[leftIndex] into destination[destinationIndex]
         increment rightIndex
         increment destinationIndex
    }
}
```

If you translate what I've written directly into Java, you'll probably get `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exceptions. You need to add extra code in the `while` statement to make it do the right thing when one of the indexes is past the end of its array.